# Getting a dialogue box of custom scripts

Tags: key-bindings, menus

I have a bunch of scripts for managing files/directories that I use on a regular basis. Would it be possible to assign a key binding such that whenever I hit this key binding I get a dialogue box that lists my scripts within emacs and I can choose one to execute on the fly?

This may be fairly obvious but I couldn't find anything about this online possibly because I do not know what the term to search for is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `easy-menu-define` for defining a popup menu and a menu in the menu bar.
If you need to extend the menu later on you can use `easy-menu-add-item`.

Example:

```el
(defun foo ()
  "Just an example script."
  (interactive)
  (message "*foo*"))

(defun bar ()
  "Just another example script."
  (interactive)
  (message "*bar*"))

(easy-menu-define
  my-script-menu
  global-map
  "My Scripts"
  '("Scripts" ["Call foo" foo t])) ;; List of all menu items which you know when you create the menu.

(easy-menu-add-item ;; For adding menu items later on.
 global-map
 '(menu-bar Scripts)
 ["Call bar" bar :keys ""])

(defun my-open-script-menu ()
  "Open a popup menu at mouse location with my scripts."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((key-list (x-popup-menu t my-script-menu)) ;; x-popup-menu returns a list of events.
     (key-sequence (vconcat key-list)) ;; ... but key sequences are vectors
     (command (lookup-key my-script-menu key-sequence))) ;; now looking up the key sequence in the keymap
    (when (commandp command) ;; when successful call the command
      (call-interactively command))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") #'my-open-script-menu)
```